# What type are Lists of any type in Perl 6?

Tags: list, raku

Consider the following Python code (as an example):

```
a = 5 
b = "a"
l = [a, b] # -> typing.List[typing.Any]
print(l)   
# [5, "a"]
```

The type of list `l` is *`list`*; it is not constrained by the types it holds because Python is quite dynamically typed.

Contrast this with, say, Go, which is strongly structurally typed:

```
var list []uint8{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

That list can only hold unsigned integers up to 255. It cannot hold any other type.

Also Go:

```
var multi interface{"string", []int{9, 5}, rune('5'), []interface{}}
```

Interfaces allow for containers of variant types.

---

Consider Perl 6, which is even more dynamically typed than Python in that `say 6 + "1";` will give `7`, the integer. (Who thought this was a good idea I don't know.)

I like gradual typing in my programs as (especially for Perl 6, which I'm learning) it improves readability and maintanability.

Neither of the following work:

```
use strict;
my Int $n = 6;
my Str $x = "a";
my Int @l = $n, $x;
```

nor

```
use strict;    
my Int $n = 6;
my Str $x = "a";
my List @l = $n, $x;
```

You get `Type check failed in assignment to @l; expected List but got Int`. (Other list construction syntaxes (`[vals]`, `<vals>`) give the same error).

What *does* work is saying the type is `Any` (or `Mu`) which makes sense. (Well, it makes sense to me because `Any`'s the same keyword Python 3.5 uses.)

```
use strict;    
my Int $n = 6;
my Str $x = "a";
my Any @l = $n, $x;
```

But using `Any` or `Mu` kinda defeats the purpose of type checking in the first place.

What's the type of a list, if it's not `List`? Moreover, why is `my List $blah;` valid syntax if the type check will never pass for any value or List thereof?

Comment: Using the infix numeric addition operator `+` for anything other than numeric addition is a stupid idea, having a separate operator for string concatenation makes much more sense.

Comment: Which version of Rakudo are you using (`perl6 -e 'say $*PERL.compiler'`)? `my Int $n = 6;my Int @l = $n, $n;` works fine for me (don't bother with anything before 2015.12). Also there is almost no reason to have `use strict` in a Perl 6 program as it is the default.

Comment: @BradGilbert I pasted the wrong example. This is `rakudo (2015.12.219.gd.67.cb.3)`, but I see the answer to this question now.

Comment: You could get the Python behaviour for `+` by adding a candidate to it `multi infix:<+> ( \l, Str \r ){ l~r }; say say 6 + "1"` => `61␤` don't do that though.

Comment: `@l.WHAT.say` prints `(Array)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You interpreted it wrong, at least *list* in Python is different from *list* in Perl6, it's actually like array in Perl6 (and Perl6 *list* is like Python *tuple*).

When you do:

```
my List @l = $n, $n;
```

[you create an array `@l`](http://doc.perl6.org/language/list#The_%40_sigil) and [enforce all its elements must be](http://doc.perl6.org/language/list#Typing)  type [`List`](http://doc.perl6.org/type/List).

So your second example:

```
use strict;
my Int $n = 6;
my Int @l = $n, $n;
```

must work.

The code:

```
my Any @l = $n, $x;
```

is the same as:

```
my @l = $n, $x;
```

You have allowed the elements of array `@l` to be any type.

Comment: I think it's really weird that the same syntax tells what an object *is* and what *types an object is a container for*, but I guess I'm just not used to sigils, at all.

Comment: @cat: If you read this http://doc.perl6.org/language/containers, you can see it's reasonable.

Comment: @cuonglm: Nit: aiui, and according to tests right now to verify, `my @array ...` is the same as `my Mu @array is default(Any)`. This mostly doesn't matter but it makes things work out nicely when it matters.

Comment: @cat It doesn't, actually.  When you say `my Int $x;`, you are not saying that `$x` *is* an `Int`, you are saying that the `Scalar` `$x` *contains* an `Int`.  This is just more obvious with arrays.

Comment: @darch So in `my List @l`, you are not saying that `@l` is a list, you are saying that the `Positional` `@l` contains a collection of `List` objects?

Answer (score 6):

If you want elements of a list to be type-checked, then you can use binding `:=` instead of assignment `=`:

```
my Int $n =   6;
my Str $x = "a";

# Bind $n and $x to elements of @bound
my @bound := $n, $x;

@bound[1].say;       # Prints "a"
@bound[1] = "Hello"; # Changing the second element changes $x
$x.say;              # Prints "Hello"

@bound[1] = 6; # Dies with error "Type check failed in assignment to $x; expected Str but got Int"
```

Notice that the error created by that last line refers to `$x`, not `@bound[1]`.