# How is this Perl sensical, considering Perl 6's type system?

Tags: types, raku

<sup>I was gonna edit this into [my other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997353/what-type-are-lists-of-any-type-in-perl-6), but it feels different enough and I don't want to ask too many questions per question.</sup>

---

My mind... has exploded.

Consider:

```perl
use strict;

my Int $n = 6;
my Str $x = "a";
my @l = $n, $x;
say @l ~~ List;
```

Prints `True`, as expected.

Consider, then:

```perl
use strict;

my Int $n = 6;
my Str $x = "a";
my List @l = $n, $x; # <-- only change is the type notation
say @l ~~ List;
```

Which dies with:

```
Type check failed in assignment to @l; expected List but got Int
```

So... the type of List is List but I can't *say* it's List because that's a sin!

What's going on here? Is this a bug? Or am I bringing my irrelevant Python and Go idioms to Perl and breaking things?

Comment: @Hunter, you made the pretty colours go away! (The reason I tagged it with [tag:perl] is so I could have syntax highlighting, but if you think organisation is more important then fair enough.)

Comment: Apparently the perl6 tag doesn't have a default syntax highlighting hint associated with it. I've added Perl 5 hints for now. I haven't used Perl 6, but I'm guessing the syntax is close enough that the highlighting should be the same. Maybe I'll make a request on Meta.

Comment: I think it's fine to also include the `perl` tag on Perl 6 questions, @Hunter. I see a number of Perl 6 questions with both tags, and the [perl tag wiki includes both](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info): "Perl is a family of high-level, general-purpose, interpreted, dynamic programming languages. The languages in this family include Perl 5 and Perl 6." If you think it should be otherwise, maybe post a question on Meta to get feedback from the community.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot There is quite a bit of new syntax, actually. Sometimes even vim has a hard time dealing with it, in my experience.

Comment: @cat In Perl 6, strictures are on by default. I was actually surprised that `use strict` didn't throw an error.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Good to know. Are the differences pronounced enough that the highlighting on SO is consistently bad/wrong? Google prettify is simplistic enough that it screws up Perl 5 highlighting sometimes, but it's fine for most questions, and generally better than no highlighting at all.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot For this question, it works fine. For other questions, it just depends on how much of the "new" syntax people are using.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think a post on Meta would be a good idea to get feedback, I for instance think the separation would be beneficial both for organization and getting the "right" people to look at the question. Knowledge of Perl5 doesn't imply any knowledge of Perl6. Users could subscribe to both if they were interested in both languages.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315419/should-perl6-questions-be-tagged-with-the-perl-tag-as-well

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Thanks for asking on Meta, I'll try to post an answer at some point, although I still haven't made up my mind about which approach is better.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: *I was actually surprised that `use strict` didn't throw an error* - note that Perl6 still comes with a lax mode that can be enabled lexically via `no strict` (and disabled via `use strict`); if I remember correctly, `-e` was supposed to use lax mode by default

Comment: @Christoph `-e` was originally going to be in lax mode by default but it made it so that writing the wrong variable name wasn't caught by the compiler. Which proved to be more annoying than having to declare them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
my List @l = $n, $x;
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't declare that `@l` is a `List`.  It declares that the elements of `@l` will be `List`s.  You don't need to declare that `@l` will be an array; you already did that when you used the sigil.

You can move the explosion around by replacing `List` with `Int` to make Perl 6 expect a list of `Int`s.

Comment: @cat You can force it to be a particular class of Positional `my class MyArray does Positional {...}; my @a is MyArray;` This is useful for some uses of hashes `my %h is SetHash; %h{$_}++ for 'HelloWorld'.comb; say %h` => `SetHash.new(r, l, W, H, e, d, o)␤` You currently can't combine this syntax with assignment though which makes `my @a is List;` rather pointless as you can't ever assign any elements to it (The default being Array which is mutable).

Comment: @BradGilbert: but you can use binding; a `my @a is List` variable cannot be bound to things that do not derive from `List`

Comment: @Christoph I thought I tried binding after the declaration, I guess I didn't.

Answer (score 10):

```
my List @l;
```

is shorthand notation for

```
my @l is Array of List;
```

which places a `List` type constraint on the *elements* of the array.

The type constraint on the container is already expressed via the `@` sigil, corresponding to the role `Positional`, whereas a `%` sigil corresponds to the role `Associative`.

The case of `$` variables is similar insofar as there's also a container involved (a `Scalar`) with a constraint on its single element. However, the constraint also allows direct rebinding to a decontainerized value<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> If the above does not make sense to you, you should look into the difference between assignment `=` and binding `:=`. It might also be instructive to inspect the variable via `.VAR.WHAT`.

Note that we can also rebind to another scalar container as long as its *element* meets the type constraint at time of binding.

This can be used to subvert the type system:

```
my Int $a;
my $b = 42;
$a := $b;
$b = "not cool";
say $a;
```

Not cool :(

Comment: Is that cheating of the type system intentionally allowed?

Comment: @cat: looks like a bug (or at the very least a misfeature) to me; I can't think of anything obvious that would prevent fixing this

Comment: This is not a bug. `my Int $a` creates a scalar container of type Int and with default of Int (that does not got a name) and binds the locally scoped name `$a` to it. With `my $b = 42` you create a container of type Any and default Any and assign 42 to it. The binding of `$a` to `$b` changes the container of `$a` to the container of `$b`. The original container that `$a` was bound to is lost. Now the container of `$a` is of type Any and default Any.

If the type constraint would stick to the _name_ `$a`, you would never be able to bind anything to anything.

Comment: @gfldex: I'm pretty sure I had a test case where the constraint survived the rebinding (possibly due to some static analysis?), but I cannot reproduce it; I'll see if I can figure out what I did before...

Comment: @gfldex: I might have been mistaken; however, what does survive is the constraint on rebinding the variable, eg `my Int $a; my $b = 42; $a := $b; $a := Str`

Comment: @Christoph I've filed bug report RT#127443 Binding / bound variables don't honor binder variable's type constraint